# Redirect song name from JPlayer HTML5 audio player

Tags: jquery, css, html, jplayer

I'm using JPlayer as an HTML5 audio player. In part of it's jQuery, it takes the name of a song in it's playlist and displays it as a list elemnt. I'd like to take that name-displaying function and redirect it to a different place.

@Bender's answer below works when playing the songs via clicking on their thumbnails, but does not update the name if using the player's controls to skip to the previous or next song, or letting the player cycle through the playlist. It also doesn't display the name when the page is first loaded.

In JPlayer's code there's a section that adds a class (.jp-playlist-current) to the song that's cued up and active (either played or paused). I think utilizing that would be best.. But am unsure how to go about it, as the "name" section of JPlayer's control isn't specifically called out.

```
{
name:"Paparazzi",
mp3:"http://www.minimalpluscreative.com/newclients/fernandogaribay/audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.mp3",
oga:"http://www.minimalpluscreative.com/newclients/fernandogaribay/audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.ogg",
wav:"http://www.minimalpluscreative.com/newclients/fernandogaribay/audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.wav"
}
```

That is.. move the name to a paragraph called #name and always display the current songs name.. no matter how you get there.

Anyway, not sure exactly where or how to do this. Any advice?

Thank you!

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/MmvJX/7/

---

```
           playlistConfig: function(index) {
                $(this.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + this.current).removeClass("jp-playlist-current").parent().removeClass("jp-playlist-current");
                $(this.cssSelector.playlist + "_item_" + index).addClass("jp-playlist-current").parent().addClass("jp-playlist-current");
                this.current = index;
                //Line below this
                $('#name').text(this.playlist[this.current].name);
                $(this.cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("setMedia", this.playlist[this.current]);
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

In your jplayer.playlist.js file add a line like the following to the `_highlight` function with the correct my_jquery_selector for the div you'd like the title to be printed in:

```
$(my_jquery_selector).html(this.playlist[index].title);
```

This is jacked from the current final line of that method that sets the title div (this.cssSelector.title)in the player itself.  The `_highlight` function is called any time a song/media change is called so I think that should do it for you every time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, so here's what I interpreted. Look what I modified, as it's nothing hard to do. Do you know how to code in JavaScript/jQuery, by any chance?

http://jsfiddle.net/MmvJX/5/

Comment: @Blender edited the question to clarify it. Looked at your jsFiddle.. couldn't find the modification (did some searches for now_playing and name).

I understand the theory and methods for coding jQuery (not native JavaScript) and can get basic function done, but the stuff I post on this site is out of my reach. Luckily all you techie experienced dev people know what's up and I pick up on the edits. I try not to ask the same question twice.

Comment: It's this teeny line: `$('#name').text($(this).html());`. Search for `$(this).blur();`, and it's near the last occurrence.

Comment: And by **move the name**, do you mean move the link out of place, or just show the name of the song being played in a different place?

Comment: @Blender. I love it. You're a champion. Can I give kudos, too?

Comment: I'd dissect the code and check what each part does, as you'll benefit from doing that. I just managed to find the correct place on my first try...

Comment: @Blender. I try to. Usually copy/pasting from functions that I know work, or commenting out sections to see what breaks. I really appreciate the advice.

Comment: Generic advice, to the rescue!

Comment: @Blender, after playing around with it some more I realized that the name is only shown if you click it's thumbnail. If you use the player's play button and it starts cold, no name is shown. Do you have a recommendation for using the jp-playlist-current class to show what's currently playing regardless of how it was started?

Comment: There should be an initialization function of some sort. I'm too lazy to find it...

Comment: @Blender fair enough! I appreciate your help the same

Answer (score 1):

I know how.

CODE:

```
...

var cssSelector = {
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
};
var playlist = [];

var options = {
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.1.0/js", 
    supplied: "oga, mp3", 
    volume: 0.6,
    // <<< HERE <<< Set up "on play" event of jPlayer
    play: function(event) { // Add a listener for anything we want when play began
        var cur_media = event.jPlayer.status.media;
        // ... ENTER YOUR CODE HERE
        // cur_media.author - Thats my handwrited Author, see below
        // cur_media.title - Song title
        // Another cur_media.xxxxxxxx - Other data fields that we typed (see below)
    },
    _:''
};

var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);

...

var listSitePrefix = 'http://www.example.com/';

myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
{
    author: "John Connor",
    title: "Ultimate Artist - Brand New Song",
    mp3: listSitePrefix + "music/01.mp3",
    oga: listSitePrefix + "music/01.ogg"
},

...

]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for remark. I wrote explaination inside code in comments, but well, this is not obvious. Decision for given problem is providing callback function in option 'play' of _var options_, with which our exemplar of jPlayerPlaylist will be created.